# Unexpected HTML token from html.NewTokenizer.Token()

Tags: html, go

I am trying to list all the tokens found in a web page. The core is in the function

```
func find_links(httpBody io.Reader) []string {

    links := make([]string, 0)
    page := html.NewTokenizer(httpBody)
    for {
        tokenType := page.Next()
        if tokenType == html.ErrorToken {
            return links
        }
        token := page.Token()
        fmt.Println("Now token is ", token)
    }
}
```

When I print the output I obtain something like

```
Now token is  <body>
Now token is

Now token is  <header>
```

I don't understand what the second token is and why it is printing an extra blank line.

Full code of a working example [here](http://play.golang.org/p/ivYtzLjfFa), even if it can't run on playground because of the missing http package

Comment: Looks like you're matching a carriage-return as a token. (note: absolutely no knowledge of go, so I can't help you fix it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second token is a [TextToken](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.net/html#TextToken) containing a newline.

Change the print to

```
   fmt.Printf("Now token is %T %v\n", token, token)
```

to see the types of the tokens.

Comment: This would explain the second line; but I still don't understand why I have a blank line